# Injecting template content from parent into child

Tags: angular

I have a 3rd party library component that I am trying to customize by adding some additional markup at a certain point.  I am using a structural directive to do this and currently I am programmatically adding and styling nodes using the renderer like so:

```
  const headerDiv = this.newDiv();
   el = this.nativeElement.querySelector('div.ui-dropdown-items-wrapper');
   this.renderer.appendChild(el, this.renderer.createText('sometext'));


  private newDiv(): Element {
   return this.renderer.createElement('div');
 }
```

The markup is like so:

```
<div #containerDiv>
  <child-component *myStructuralDirective>
  </child-component>
</div>
```

is there a way to define an `<ng-template>` directly in the parent component's markup and inject that at a certain point using the renderer?  Something like this:

```
<div #containerDiv>
  <child-component *myStructuralDirective>
  </child-component>
</div>
<ng-template #footer>
   <p>Some other markup</p>
</ng-template>
```

and then inject the content of #footer at some point of my choosing into the child-component.  Note - I have no access to the child since it's a compiled 3rd party lib.

The gist of this is that I am trying to see if there is a better way to define the markup as a template variable that I can use in my structural directive, get access to that template and inject it at a certain point in the child component.

Edit - 
I am looking at `ViewContainerRef.insert`, unfortunately this can insert templates only based on location of other `ViewRef`s.  Since I cannot change the markup of the 3rd party component I can define a `ng-container` to mark the point of insertion and have to only use CSS selectors.  Not sure if there is a way to insert a template based on a element location.  I know these are 2 discrete concepts (Angular View abstractions vs direct DOM insertion) so i'm not optimistic this can be done!

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can inject ng-template to wherever you want it to be placed either with these following methods:

1.) Using **ng-container**

```
 <div #containerDiv>
  <child-component *myStructuralDirective></child-component>

  // This will show your template
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="footer"></ng-container>  

</div>

<ng-template #footer>
   <p>Some other markup</p>
</ng-template>
```

2.) Or Inject it using a **structural directive** with a ViewContainerRef & CreateEmbeddedView

> ```
> a.)Supply the footer template on your childComponent. myStructuralDirective
> is now both a directive and an [] input that asks for a value.
>
> <child-component [myStructuralDirective]="footer"></child-component>
>
> b.) Use default ViewContainerRef declared on the constructor which pertains 
> to your current view/screen which the template the template is attached example for this - it is attached on ChildComponentView
>
> @Directive({
>     selector: 'myStructuralDirective'
> })
> export class MyStructuralDirective implements AfterViewInit {
>
>  @Input() myStructuralDirective: TemplateRef<any>;
>
>  constructor(private container: ViewContainerRef) {}
>
>  ngAfterViewInit() {
>      this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.myStructuralDirective);
>   }
> ```
>
> }

3.) Or Supply an @Input() on your ChildComponent passing the footer template value

> ```
>  a.)  <child-component *myStructuralDirective
>                        [footerTemplate]="footer"></child-component>
>
>  b.) On the ChildComponent Class, declare its @Input() property
>
>  @Component({
>      selector: 'child-component'
>   })
>   export class ChildComponent {
>
>     @Input() footerTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
>
>   }
>
>  c.) On your ChildComponent Template, supply an ng-container to wherever you want it to be placed.
>
>  <h1>Header</h1>
>  <h1>Content</h1>
>
>  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="footerTemplate"></ng-container>
> ```

4.) Or you can supply a container on your **ChildComponent**

> a.) ChildComponent Sample Template
>
> ```
> <p>Header</p> 
> <p>Content</p>
>
> <div #container></div>
> ```
>
> b.) Declare ViewContainerRef and TemplateRef on your ChildComponent Class with the @Input() that requires the footer template value from the component
>
> ```
> @Component({...})
> export class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {
>
>   //From your template <div #container></div> 
>   @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;
>
>   @Input() footerTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
>
>
>   ngAfterViewInit() {
>      this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.footerTemplate);
> }
> ```
>
> }

*Your ng-template will now appear on your desired location.*

Comment: thanks, but this is not what I am asking for.  I can't modify any of the markup in the child and I have to insert the template at an arbitrary point *inside* the child using just css selectors to select the point of insertion.